# Logical operators in graph database (neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, logical-operators, business-logic

Edit: possible duplicate of: [neo4j logic gate simulation, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679184/neo4j-logic-gate-simulation-how-to/16705114#16705114)

I have a neo4j database that contains Options, OptionValues, Configurations, Products and LogicalNodes. In concrete, a Configuration is just a collection of selected OptionValues, one for each Option. LogicalNodes on the other hand try to link which combinations of OptionValues point to one (or multiple) specific products.

Here I have an example:
[image]

You can see that in this graph there are 3 options, 2 with 2 OptionValues and one with only 1 OptionValue. Every OptionValue is linked to a Product through one or more LogicalNodes. LogicalNodes can be linked one to another and there are 3 types of LogicalNodes (AND, OR, NOT (not shown)).

Now my question, I know how to get all products related to a given Configuration, not taking LogicalNodes into account, using this cypher: `MATCH p = (:Configuration {Id:"CONF1ID"})-[r1*]->(pi:ProductInstance) return pi`

However, I fail to come up with a query that uses the LogicalNodes to filter out invalid paths. An invalid (sub)path would be when:

1. a LogicalNode where Type equals "AND" has more incoming :HAS_LOGIC
   relations than there are in the path.
2. a LogicalNode where Type equals "NOT" has incoming :HAS_LOGIC
   relations that exist in the path.

Has anyone ever tried to model a graph containing logical information in the graph and stumbled accross a solution?